# Should we change the master and slaves config file for a Hadoop cluster in all nodes?

Tags: hadoop

I know that we should put the IP address of the master node in conf/master file and put the IP addresses of all slave nodes in conf/slaves file one per each single line. My question is should we do this only on the master node or we should also change these two files on all slave nodes as well? Furthermore, If I want the master node to be as a DataNode and TaskTracker as well, should I put the IP address of master in slaves file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conf/slaves`, `conf/master` configuration files should be maintained only on master nodes not in slave nodes .`conf/masters` files is used for specifying the `secondarynamenode` host.  `start-all.sh` consists of `start-mapred.sh and start-dfs.sh`. If you want to start `Job tracker` on a node then start-mapred.sh script should be executed on that node and based on it's conf/slaves files all `Tasktracker` services will be started on mentioned nodes.

Similarly `start-dfs.sh` script should be executed in `Namenode` machine, based on the values of `conf/masters` and `conf/slaves`, `secondarynamenode` and `Datanodes` will be started on the corresponding nodes respectively.